# Problems Initializing Vector

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ so I'm kind of consfused
I wanted to do something like that:

`

```
 int max = 30;

    class MyClass{
     vector<int> data(max);
    };
```

but it wasn't working, because it was not recognizing that "max" was that int I had just initialized.
  so i changed to that:

```
class MyClass{
     MyClass();
     int max;
     vector<int> data(max);
    }
MyClass::MyClass(){
  max = 40;}
```

Don't work unless I initialize the vector in the constructor, but I don't know the correct sintax.

How can I make this work? All I want is to initialize "max" and then use it as the initial size of the vector.

Comment: Hmm.... maybe the most efficient way for you to get good at C++ is to sit down for a few hours with a good book and work through some simpler examples.

Comment: It's a college homework.The teacher asked for it in the first week of learning c++

Comment: Did the teacher ban books? I don't think *reading* would constitute some sort of moral violation.

Comment: Coming to stackoverflow and asking questions is also a good way to learn (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prof/teacher should have told you about initializer lists. The syntax looks something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> data;
public:
    MyClass(int max) : data(max) { }
};
```

Comment: When you create a `MyClass` object. If you want `data` to start with a fixed size, you can just pass that directly, as in: `MyClass() : data(40){}`.

Comment: I do want it to start with a fixed size, but I need the variable because I will use it later in a function.

Comment: @Johnsmith: be aware that there are both `.capacity()` and `.size()`, but they're different things. `.capacity` is the size it could grow to without re-allocating memory; `.size()` is the number of items currently in the collection (and is by far the more often used of the two).